# How to dynamically switch between firebase and firestore as the database and dispatch redux actions accordingly

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux, google-cloud-firestore

My project used firebase real-time database as the database for users, but now the users are being migrated to firestore. So the migrated and new users are mapped to firestore using a cloud function. The other users will be in firebase RTDB.

I store the result of the cloud function in a redux state. 
What is an efficient way to dynamically import actions for firebase and firestore separately?

Currently I've tried a method as follows:

```
export const addEntry = (entry) => ({
    type: ADD_ENTRY,
    entry
});
```

```
export const addEntryToFirebase = (entry) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { db } = getState().userinfo; // will return 'firebase' or 'firestore'
    if (db === 'firebase') {
        // code to add entry to firebase RTDB
    } else {
        // code to add entry to firestore
    }
}
```

However, I feel that this method is extremely inefficient. I want to know better methods to do this; maybe dynamically import files based on redux state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - If you are using webpack, and size is one of your concern then I think you should dynamically import firebase db or firestore dependencies. 
I created a class for my project which imports the dependency & initialise firebase based on the parameter I pass. This is an example, you can draw inspiration to create one for yourself

```
export class Firebase {
  static firebase;
  static initialized = false;
  static initializingPromise = false;

  static init(kubricConfig) {
    if (!Firebase.initialized && !Firebase.initializingPromise) {
      Firebase.initializingPromise = Promise.all([
          import(/* webpackChunkName: "firebase" */ 'firebase/app'),
          import(/* webpackChunkName: "firebase" */ 'firebase/auth'),
          import(/* webpackChunkName: "firebase" */ 'firebase/database'),
          import(/* webpackChunkName: "firebase" */ 'firebase/firestore'),
        ])
        .then(([firebase]) => {
          if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
            firebase.initializeApp(!kubricConfig ? __kubric_config__);
          }
          Firebase.firebase = firebase;
          Firebase.prodApp = !kubricConfig ? firebase.initializeApp(__kubric_config__.auth, "authApp") : firebase.initializeApp(kubricConfig.auth, "authApp");
          Firebase.initialized = true;
          Firebase.initializing = false;
          return firebase;
        });
    }
    return Firebase.initializingPromise;
  }

  static getInstance() {
    if (Firebase.initialized) {
      return Firebase.firebase;
    } else {
      throw new Error("Firebase not initialized");
    }
  }

  static getProdApp() {
    if (Firebase.initialized) {
      return Firebase.prodApp;
    } else {
      throw new Error("Firebase not initialized");
    }
  }
}
```

Second - If you are trying to support your users whose data is still on firebase realtime db, you can adopt some of the practices which might help

1. Write a wrapper/adapter function over firebase, the application should not be aware of the firebase apis, rather it should depend on your api. So, whenever there is an update you should not be changing code everywhere and confine changes to the adapter. Redux should not contain any logic of all this.
2. Use cloud function database functions to migrate data from realtime db to firestore. On update event, you can write parallely to firestore, so all active user data can move into firestore.
   https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events
3. Use some global config which defines the version of api or method, that indicates what the datasource should be, store or db based upon some flag stored in the data.
4. Migrate data asap!

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. But, there are 2 things that I would like to reinstate: 
1. I run a cloud function to get the check the DB corresponding to the user. 
2. The logic to handle the CRUD actions differ based on the database - so I want to dynamically dispatch the logic for a particular action based on the database

Comment: It is not necessary for me that the firestore dependency is imported dynamically; rather just the code to handle the CRUD actions.

Comment: Are you using a cloud function to enter the data or using the firebase sdk?

Comment: Thank you very much! I am using firebase SDK to enter the data. I would really appreciate if you could provide/suggest some resources to write wrapper/adapter functions over firebase as I am relatively a newbie..

Comment: This is a quick read which can help you to understand what adapters are. Its always advised to write adapters for third party libraries https://softwarebrothers.co/blog/adapter-pattern-in-node-js/

Comment: Also, kindly upvote the answer if you found it useful, thanks.